# How enable search in Select2 with JSON via Ajax request?

Tags: jquery

data is retrive successfully in select2 dropdown but search not working ...please any help will be apreciated
here is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
        ajax: {
            url: " <?php echo base_url();?>index.php/site/getdatabyajax3",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "GET",
            quietMillis: 50,
            data: function (term) {
                return {
                    term: term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                var myResults = [];
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    myResults.push({
                        'id': item.id,
                        'text': item.text
                    });
                });
                return {
                    results: myResults
                };
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: data in the select2.js drpdown retrive from database  but search not working;

Comment: Are you executing it from a bootstrap modal?

Comment: Can you create a JSfiddle that demonstrates the issue?  This will make it easier diagnose.

Comment: no there is no bootstrap model